# Is it possible to change a specific element of an array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to change a specific element of an array in numpy? Say I had an array of 12 zeros shape (3, 4):

```
0 0 0     
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

and I wanted to change the second row and 2nd element to be 8. Is there a command in numpy that allows me to do this or no?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses. I didn't realise it was as easy as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three cheers for indexing!

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((3,4))
arr[1,1] = 8
```

This works because the indexing first selects second row starting from 0 and and then second item from 0 too.

Or `arr[1][1]=8` will work for both numpy arrays and python lists!!

Answer (score 0):

simple as that...

```
arr = np.zeros((3,4))
arr[1][1] = 8 # or arr[1,1] = 8
>>> arr
[ [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 8, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign with indexing..

```
arr[1,1]=8
```